# Extension for CollectionType with element of certain type ignores subtypes

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, swift-extensions

I'm trying to create an extension for collection types containing elements of a certain type FooType and this works just fine:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == FooClass
{
    func doSomething()
}

let collectionType = [FooClass]()
collectionType.doSomething()
```

My problem is that I also want this extension to work for collection types that contain subclasses of the Foo class:

```
let collectionType = [FooSubclass]()
collectionType.doSomething()    // Doesn't work
```

I could possibly override the "==" operator and and loop through the chain of super classes until I've got a match but not sure if this is the right way to do it.

```
public func ==(t0: Any.Type?, t1: Any.Type?) -> Bool
```

Am I missing something in my where clause that could solve this or am I doing this totally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:` instead of `==`.

Try:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element: FooClass {
```